# Grails redirect without https

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have http://domain.com, I can access to http://domain.com too (secure channel).

My problem is when I try to login into https, I got:

1) I see form, fill data, and submit to https://domain.com/j_spring_security_check

2) In Login/index I redirect to https://domain.com/panel/index: **redirect (controller: "panel", action:'index')**

3) In Panel/index I redirect to **redirect(uri:'/cuentas')** but I got http://domain.com/ without https

I see that the **problem is when I'm using redirect with uri param**.

I have grails.serverURL = "http://domain.com" (without https), but I read, that serverURL is used only when I add **absolute: true** to **redirect** call.

Note: I debuged this info with Tamper Data plugin in Firefox.

Regards.

Comment: What do you actually get redirected to when you make the redirect call in step 3? Is it just `http://domain.com/` or `http://domain.com/cuentas`?

Comment: After login, **Login/index** redirect to **Panel/index** and here, I call to **redirect(uri:"/cuentas")** but instead of go to **httpS://domain.com/cuentas** y go to **http://domain.com**

Comment: I got the no https part, but does it literally just redirect you to `http://domain.com` with no `/cuentas`?